# Is there a way to differentiate GCE Instance vs GKE Instance while listing GCP Instances

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

When listing VM instances in GCP using API call that returns all instances available in the GCP which include GCE Instances and GKE Instances. How do I differentiate GCE Instance and GKE Instance?

Answer (score 2):

The node created by GKE has a special label `goog-gke-node`.

[image]

You can filter them with this [API call](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/list) and with a filter

```
GET "https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/<projectID>/zones/<zone>/instances?filter=(labels.goog-gke-node%3D%22%22)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Running the following command should list all instances from Compute engine and GKE.

```
gcloud compute instances list
```

Looks like an instance created from GKE will be in the following format gke-[nameofcluster]-........ . That is one way to differentiate with the name.

Now if for whatever reason you somehow followed the same format when creating your Compute Engine VMs, you can just describe a VM and those with reference to the word gke tells you that it was created from GKE

```
gcloud compute instances describe gke-nameofcluster-xxxxxx-xxxxxxx | grep gke
```

You will see over 30 references to gke related to labels and managed groups etc. You will just know it when you see it.

Answer (score 0):

- When using the [instances.aggregatedList](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/aggregatedList) method to retrieve the list of GCE instances in a project, there is  a [Query parameter](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/aggregatedList#query-parameters) called **filter** which filters resources listed in the response. So, we can make use of this parameter to list only GKE instances or any GCE instance in specific.
- **For example:** The Label **“goog-gke-node”: ””** is an unique resource that is part of GKE instance’s metadata by default, use this as a filter to list only the GKE instances. To do this we can use the string `labels.goog-gke-node = ""` as the value of the filter parameter in API call. Refer to the API explorer [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/aggregatedList?apix_params=%7B%22project%22%3A%22sample-project-id%22%2C%22filter%22%3A%22labels.goog-gke-node%20%3D%20%5C%22%5C%22%22%7D), which has the pre-populated filter parameter value, this when executed after replacing `project's` value with Project ID will list GKE instances only. Similarly, we can make use of other resource that is unique to a set of GCE instances as well.